# Biblatex and Musixtex clash

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, errors, musixtex

I'm having several problems while writing my dissertation due to the fact that Biblatex (using a biber backend) and Musixtex seem to clash.

One such problem is placing Musixtex notes in text, while another seems to be spacing issues in the references.

I've added the following in my preamble, as per [Miramoto's suggestion](https://www.mail-archive.com/tex-music@tug.org/msg03178.html):

```
\let\mxaddspace\addspace\let\addspace\relax
```

and then reset \addspace as can be seen in the example below:

```
\\def\notesintext#1{% no staff lines, no clefs
{\let\addspace\mxaddspace\let\extractline\relax
   \setlines10\smallmusicsize \nobarnumbers \nostartrule
   \staffbotmarg0pt \setclefsymbol1\empty
   \startextract\addspace{-\afterruleskip}#1\zendextract}}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrcc}
 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Note Name}} & \textbf{Timebase Value} & \textbf{**kern Value} \\ \hline
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\wh1\en}}
 & Semibreve                              & 96                      & 1                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\hup1\en}}& Dotted Minim                           & 72                      & 2.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\hu1\en}}& Minim                                  & 48                      & 2                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\qup1\en}}& Dotted Crotchet                        & 36                      & 4.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\hu1\en}}& Minim Triplet                          & 32                      & 3.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\qu1\en}}& Crotchet                               & 24                      & 4                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cup1\en}}& Dotted Quaver                          & 18                      & 8.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\qu1\en}}& Crotchet Triplet                       & 16                      & 6                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cu1\en}}& Quaver                                 & 12                      & 8                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccup1\en}}& Dotted Semiquaver                      & 9                       & 16.                 \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\cu1\en}}& Quaver Triplet                         & 8                       & 12                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccu1\en}}& Semiquaver                             & 6                       & 16                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cccu1\en}}& Dotted Demisemiquaver                  & 4.5                     & 32.                 \\
 & Semiquaver Triplet                     & 4                       & 24                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cccu1\en}}& Demisemiquaver                         & 3                       & 32                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccccu1\en}}& Hemidemisemiquaver                     & 1.5                     & 64                 
\end{tabular}
\caption{A comparison of the representation of the duration of musical events using an appropriate timebase representation}
\label{tbl:kern-timebase-representation}
\end{table}
```

Unfortunately, this does not display the table and also does not throw any errors, so I'm not exactly sure where to begin debugging this.

**Edit:** I've attached a minimum working example below, which seems to display the table just fine, so it must be another package that's interfering. However, it also mangles the spacing in the reference, which I was also encountering and was hoping would be fixed when the biblatex-musixtex clash was sorted.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[style=apa,hyperref=true,autocite=inline,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{clashtest.bib}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\mxaddspace\addspace\let\addspace\relax
\usepackage{tabularx}

\def\notesintext#1{% no staff lines, no clefs
  {\let\addspace\mxaddspace\let\extractline\relax
   \setlines10\smallmusicsize \nobarnumbers \nostartrule
   \staffbotmarg0pt \setclefsymbol1\empty
   \startextract\addspace{-\afterruleskip}#1\zendextract}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}

Table~\ref{tbl:kern-timebase-representation} shows a comparison of the representation of the duration of musical events using an appropriate timebase representation from~\cite{Pearce2005} (with a granularity of~\texttt{96}), and **kern representation from~\cite{Huron1998}.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrcc}
 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Note Name}} & \textbf{Timebase Value} & \textbf{**kern Value} \\ \hline
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\wh1\en}}
 & Semibreve                              & 96                      & 1                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\hup1\en}}& Dotted Minim                           & 72                      & 2.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\hu1\en}}& Minim                                  & 48                      & 2                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\qup1\en}}& Dotted Crotchet                        & 36                      & 4.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\hu1\en}}& Minim Triplet                          & 32                      & 3.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\qu1\en}}& Crotchet                               & 24                      & 4                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cup1\en}}& Dotted Quaver                          & 18                      & 8.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\qu1\en}}& Crotchet Triplet                       & 16                      & 6                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cu1\en}}& Quaver                                 & 12                      & 8                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccup1\en}}& Dotted Semiquaver                      & 9                       & 16.                 \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\cu1\en}}& Quaver Triplet                         & 8                       & 12                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccu1\en}}& Semiquaver                             & 6                       & 16                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cccu1\en}}& Dotted Demisemiquaver                  & 4.5                     & 32.                 \\
 & Semiquaver Triplet                     & 4                       & 24                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cccu1\en}}& Demisemiquaver                         & 3                       & 32                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccccu1\en}}& Hemidemisemiquaver                     & 1.5                     & 64                 
\end{tabular}
\caption{A comparison of the representation of the duration of musical events using an appropriate timebase representation}
\label{tbl:kern-timebase-representation}
\end{table}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Minimum working document for spacing issues (removing the musixtex package fixes the references spacing issues):

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[style=apa,hyperref=true,autocite=inline,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{clashtest.bib}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\mxaddspace\addspace\let\addspace\relax

\begin{document}

Comparison shown of representation of the duration of musical events using an appropriate timebase representation from~\parencite{Pearce2005} (with a granularity of~\texttt{96}), and **kern representation from~\autocite{Huron1998}.

\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}, keyword={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[title={Discography}, keyword={Discography}]

\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@inproceedings{Pearce2005,
venue = {Esbjerg, Denmark},
author = {Pearce, Marcus and Conklin, Darrell and Wiggins, Geraint},
booktitle = {Computer Music Modeling and Retrieval, Second International Symposium, CMMR 2004},
doi = {10.1007/978-3-540-31807-1_22},
editor = {Wiil, Uffe Kock},
isbn = {3540244581},
number = {February},
pages = {295-312},
publisher = {{Springer-Verlag}},
title = {{Methods for Combining Statistical Models of Music}},
volume = {3310},
year = {2005},
keywords = {Bibliography}
}

@misc{Huron1998,
author = {Huron, David},
pages = {436},
title = {{Humdrum User's Guide}},
url = {http://humdrum.ccarh.org/},
year = {1998},
keywords = {Bibliography}
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Currently, we have to guess what packages you are using, etc.

Comment: I've added a minimum working example which seems to display the table correctly, so it must be one of the packages that I've used outside of my minimum working example...

Comment: Try adding the packages until the problem reoccurs (and then delete all other unnessary packages again) - you are then more than welcome to edit your post again.

Comment: I've added all packages used in my dissertation document to my minimum working example, and the example seems to compile fine, as the table appears correctly :/

Comment: Then try to add all the other code after the same principle - at some stage the problem will occur again.

Comment: I've tracked the problem down to the use of `\let\clearpage\relax` between the use of multiple bibliography sections; removing that in my main dissertation file fixed the issue, thanks!

The spacing issue in my references (as can be seen in the image in my main post is still present however:

First reference: no space between retrieved and from.
Second reference: no space before ampersand, no space before (Ed.)

Comment: I've provided a minimum working document of the spacing issue in the references section, as can be seen in my main post (which I have edited). Removing the \usepackage{musixtex} fixes the spacing issue in both citations and references.

Comment: @Tom Since the MWE shows the other issue, I think the best thing for Simon to do is just edit the question to explain the bibliography problem only. I've added an answer. No need for a new question.

Comment: @AlanMunn Right, I didn't think that anyone would be able to follow. You proved me wrong, thanks. I will delete this and my previous comment soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing issue is due to the fact that you clobber the `biblatex` definition of `\addspace`. So you need to do this a little bit differently.  The basic idea is to make a new command `\mxaddspace` using the `musixtex` definition, and then locally change the definition of `\addspace` in the `musixtex` contexts.  If you have other `musixtex` commands/environments they would need to be patched as well.  Depending on what they are, the patching commands of `etoolbox` might be a good way to do this.

To do this properly you also  need to load `musixtex` *before* `biblatex`, then set `\addspace` to `\relax` so that `biblatex` can give it its proper `biblatex` definition.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Pearce2005,
venue = {Esbjerg, Denmark},
author = {Pearce, Marcus and Conklin, Darrell and Wiggins, Geraint},
booktitle = {Computer Music Modeling and Retrieval, Second International Symposium, CMMR 2004},
doi = {10.1007/978-3-540-31807-1_22},
editor = {Wiil, Uffe Kock},
isbn = {3540244581},
number = {February},
pages = {295-312},
publisher = {{Springer-Verlag}},
title = {{Methods for Combining Statistical Models of Music}},
volume = {3310},
year = {2005},
keywords = {Bibliography}
}

@misc{Huron1998,
author = {Huron, David},
pages = {436},
title = {{Humdrum User's Guide}},
url = {http://humdrum.ccarh.org/},
year = {1998},
keywords = {Bibliography}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\addspace\relax
\usepackage[style=apa,hyperref=true,autocite=inline,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mxaddspace}[1]{\kern#1\global\advance\x@skip#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx}

\def\notesintext#1{% no staff lines, no clefs
  {\let\addspace\mxaddspace\let\extractline\relax
   \setlines10\smallmusicsize \nobarnumbers \nostartrule
   \staffbotmarg0pt \setclefsymbol1\empty
   \startextract\addspace{-\afterruleskip}#1\zendextract}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}

Table~\ref{tbl:kern-timebase-representation} shows a comparison of the representation of the duration of musical events using an appropriate timebase representation from~\cite{Pearce2005} (with a granularity of~\texttt{96}), and **kern representation from~\cite{Huron1998}.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrcc}
 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Note Name}} & \textbf{Timebase Value} & \textbf{**kern Value} \\ \hline
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\wh1\en}}
 & Semibreve                              & 96                      & 1                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\hup1\en}}& Dotted Minim                           & 72                      & 2.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\hu1\en}}& Minim                                  & 48                      & 2                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\qup1\en}}& Dotted Crotchet                        & 36                      & 4.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\hu1\en}}& Minim Triplet                          & 32                      & 3.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\qu1\en}}& Crotchet                               & 24                      & 4                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cup1\en}}& Dotted Quaver                          & 18                      & 8.                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\qu1\en}}& Crotchet Triplet                       & 16                      & 6                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cu1\en}}& Quaver                                 & 12                      & 8                   \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccup1\en}}& Dotted Semiquaver                      & 9                       & 16.                 \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\xtuplet3n\cu1\en}}& Quaver Triplet                         & 8                       & 12                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccu1\en}}& Semiquaver                             & 6                       & 16                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cccu1\en}}& Dotted Demisemiquaver                  & 4.5                     & 32.                 \\
 & Semiquaver Triplet                     & 4                       & 24                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\cccu1\en}}& Demisemiquaver                         & 3                       & 32                  \\
 \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\notesintext{\notes\ccccu1\en}}& Hemidemisemiquaver                     & 1.5                     & 64                 
\end{tabular}
\caption{A comparison of the representation of the duration of musical events using an appropriate timebase representation}
\label{tbl:kern-timebase-representation}
\end{table}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks for this, this completely solved my issue and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

The complementary approach to Alan's answer would be to let `musixtex` keep its definition and use the fact that `biblatex` has an internal name space.

Many of the macros `biblatex` defines are not defined everywhere in the document. Instead they are only defined in the specific context where they could be useful. This prevents those macros from clashing with other document commands and prevents their use when they don't make sense.

`\addspace` is not one of these protected commands in the internal name space, it is available everywhere in the document and so it clashes with `musixtex`'s `\addspace`. The following code moves `biblatex`'s `\addspace` into the internal name space.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\let\blx@imc@addspace\addspace
\blx@regimcs{\addspace}
\makeatother
\usepackage{musixtex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you don't use `biblatex`'s `\addspace` outside a `biblatex` context you should be fine.